# notice trying to get php

Tags: php, mysql

Im creating a form when I run across into this error

```
Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\gadgetmarket\admin\processor.php on line 37
```

the codes I used (refer below)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_meta WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $value = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
        $jj=$value->username;
        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count==1){
            // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
            $_SESSION['login'] = $jj;
            echo "success";
        }else {
            echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
```

and the error line 37 is

```
$jj=$value->username;
```

anyone knows how to get raid of this problem? any suggestions, ideas and recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, not at all, im on different issue.

Comment: fixed, its the error when not returning any rows. I already fixed it by inserting "$jj=$value->username;" inside "if($count==1){" so that when there is result then it will get the requested value else it wil not :)

Answer (score 3):

Your query is not returning any rows, causing `$value` to be assigned the value `NULL`, not a row object.

Only do your operation `$jj=$value->username;` after verifying the row count is nonzero.

Comment: yeah, i got it, its the error when not returning any rows. I already fixed it by inserting "$jj=$value->username;" inside "if($count==1){" so that when there is result then it will get the requested value else it wil not :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't be 100% positive, but this is typical when the result set is empty. You might want to try inspecting $result and $value checking for an empty set (null).

Comment: yeah, i got it, its the error when not returning any rows. I already fixed it by inserting "$jj=$value->username;" inside "if($count==1){" so that when there is result then it will get the requested value else it wil not :)